# Write just one file per window with Apache Beam Python `WriteToFiles` transform

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

need some help. I have some trivial task reading from Pub/Sub and write to batch file in GCS, but have some struggle with fileio.WriteToFiles

```
with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
  input = (p | 'ReadData' >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(topic=known_args.input_topic).with_output_types(bytes)
             | "Decode" >> beam.Map(lambda x: x.decode('utf-8'))
             | 'Parse' >> beam.Map(parse_json)
             | ' data w' >> beam.WindowInto(
                 FixedWindows(60),
                 accumulation_mode=AccumulationMode.DISCARDING
             ))

  event_data = (input
             | 'filter events' >> beam.Filter(lambda x: x['t'] == 'event')
             | 'encode et' >> beam.Map(lambda x: json.dumps(x))
             | 'write events to file' >> fileio.WriteToFiles(
                    path='gs://extention/ga_analytics/events/', shards=0))
```

I need one file after my window fires, but the number of files is equal to the number of messages from Pubsub, can anyone help me?
[current output files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FN2Z.png)
but i need only one file.

Comment: what `apache_beam` version are you using?. you might want to upgrade to newer versions. you can check out this [documentation for file naming](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.15.0/apache_beam.io.fileio.html?highlight=default_file_naming)

Comment: @tanujaa I'm using 2.24

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recently ran into this issue and dug into the source code:

fileio.WriteToFiles will attempt to output each element in the bundle as an individual file.  WireToFiles will only fallback to writing to sharded files if the number of elements exceeds the number of writers.

To force a single file to be created for all elements in the window, set max_writers_per_bundle to 0

```
WriteToFiles(shards=1, max_writers_per_bundle=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `WriteToFiles(shards=1, ...)` to limit the output to a single shard per window and triggering.

Comment: Hi @Kenn Knowles, sorry but i can't see WriteFiles method, if you mean fileio.WriteToFiles and shards=1 it dosen't work, still produce many files instead of one

Comment: @AndreyPanchenko In addition to shards=1, add a reshuffle step after the window step to group elements into windows. i.e. `| 'Group elements into windows' >>> beam.Reshuffle()`

Comment: There should be one file per window. If this is not the case, please file a bug against Beam.

Comment: Also what @PeterKim said: windowing controls aggregation and your pipeline does not have aggregation.

Comment: @KennKnowles  
appreciate for your comment but still doesn't work I added   
| 'Group elements into windows' >> beam.Reshuffle() after window step but it still producing a lot of file instead of one.

Comment: @KennKnowles I'm created issue BEAM-10998